# Carriage Returns Line feed - Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I'm new in the data analysis world and I need your help/input with something.

I have a large file with around 20 million rows or so and I want to do a find and replace statement on the file to fix examples such as indicated below:

```
chris;john;paul;darren;nick;tom;christo(CR)(LF)
pher;thomas; 
chris;john;paul;darren;nick;tom;christopher;thomas
```

fix into:

```
chris;john;paul;darren;nick;tom;christopher;thomas
chris;john;paul;darren;nick;tom;christopher;thomas
```

I have tried some function such as `[\r\n]` or just `[\r]` into extend mode, but it didn't seem to fix the problem...

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong? Bear in mind that all the lines are unique, contrary to the example above.

Comment: [\r\n] isn't a function. What do you mean by "into extend mode"? Please show the code you're having problems with and explain clearly what the issues are. Are you maybe just trying to remove all CRLF pairs?

Comment: @AlbertWinestein OP is referring to Notepad++. "Extended" [is a search mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gsss.png).

Comment: I'm obviously missing the point here. What does this have to do with Python or, indeed, sql or data-analysis for that matter

Comment: Question: Does your source file _literally_ have `(CR)(LF)`, or does it have `\r\n` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it has (CR)(LF)

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    \s*\(CR\)\(LF\)\s*
Replace: (empty)
```

Here is a working [demo](https://regex101.com/r/SYZ331/1).

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, I can see it working in the demo but it doesn't work in the actual file...

Comment: ...I can only answer to the data which you provide.  Maybe edit your question with an example where my answer is failing.

Comment: I believe that \s*\ and \s* account for spaces, the lines do not have spaces before or after the CR and LF

Comment: @christian00 That should not matter, because `\s*` matches _zero_ or more whitespace characters.  So, if they _don't_ occur before/after the `(CR)(LF)` should not matter here.

Comment: I have updated the example so that it is a bit more representative of the actual data.